# Can I change a column to have a value of the ascii of the uppercase of the first character without having to drop and recreate a table?

Tags: sql-server

Here is the DDL that I have so far. But now I realize after filling the table with data that I need to store ascii of the uppercase.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] 
(
    [PhraseId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [EnglishAscii] AS (ascii([English])) PERSISTED,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC))
);
```

Can someone tell me is it possible for me to change the `EnglishAscii` column to store the ascii value of the uppercase `[English]` column and would I be able to make the change to the table without having to drop and recreate it?

Comment: Why don't you do conversion in a stored proc or the app? Makes no sense to store it twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the English column to `UPPER` case and find the `ASCII` value

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
    [PhraseId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English]      NVARCHAR (MAX)   NOT NULL,
    [EnglishAscii] AS  (ascii(UPPER([English]))) PERSISTED,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC)
);
```

If you want to alter your existing Computed column then you have to drop the computed column and recreate it

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Phrase
DROP COLUMN EnglishAscii

ALTER TABLE dbo.Phrase
ADD EnglishAscii AS (ascii(UPPER([English]))) PERSISTED
```

Comment: but he is asking to upper case for only first letter not the entire word

Comment: @mohan111 - Prdp is correct. This will just give the uppercase of the first character

Comment: @Prdp - Can I do this as an on the fly change / update to my existing table. If so how could I change that column?

Comment: @mohan111 - Even now it will consider only the first letter

Comment: while I'm inserting sample data into this above table .I'm getting Error "The column "EnglishAscii" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator"

Comment: @Alan - Do you have computed column in your existing table ?

Comment: Yes this is the DDL for the existing table that I need to change. Can I just drop and add or can I change the column type itself?

Comment: @Alan - Check the update. You dont have to drop the table but you need to drop the computed column and recreate it

Comment: @Prdp can you please answer my comment

Comment: i have created table and trying to insert values @Prdp